# Nested foreach increasing both indexes / check if date is between 2 arrays

Tags: php, date

Is there a way to increment 2 nested foreach loops at the same time?

I have 2 arrays:

```
$datum = new DateTime("now");
$jaar = date("y",strtotime('now'));
$maand = strftime("%B");

$vakanties_start = array(
    "BeginKerst"       =>   new DateTime("$jaar-01-01"),
    "Voorjaar"         =>   new DateTime("$jaar-02-22"),
    "Mei"              =>   new DateTime("$jaar-04-25"),
    "Zomer"            =>   new DateTime("$jaar-07-18"),
    "EindKerst"        =>   new DateTime("$jaar-12-21"),
    "Test"             =>   new DateTime("$jaar-05-20")
);


$vakanties_eind = array(
    "BeginKerst"       =>   new DateTime("$jaar-01-05"),
    "Voorjaar"         =>   new DateTime("$jaar-03-01"),
    "Mei"              =>   new DateTime("$jaar-05-03"),
    "Zomer"            =>   new DateTime("$jaar-08-30"),
    "EindKerst"        =>   new DateTime("$jaar-12-31"),
    "Test"             =>   new DateTime("$jaar-05-25")
);
```

beginning of the vacation and the ending of vacations. I need to check if today is between those days.

I've tried to check that with 2 foreach loops but than i will get this error:

```
start vacation: 1-1
end vacation: 5-1

start: 1-1
end: 3-1
```

etc. etc. this obviously isn't the way I want it since that means at the end of the first foreach the holidays are between 1-1 and 31-12.

something else I tried is validating the key of the array like this:

```
    foreach ($vakanties_start as $vakantie_start){
        foreach ($vakanties_eind as $vakantie_eind){
            if ($vakantie_start->format('Y-m-d') >= $datum->format('Y-m-d') && $vakantie_eind->format('Y-m-d') <= $datum->format('Y-m-d')){
                if (key($vakantie_start) == key($vakantie_eind)){

                    echo $vakantie_start->format('Y-m-d') . "<br>" . key($vakanties_start) . "<br>";
                    echo $vakantie_eind->format('Y-m-d') . "<br>" . key($vakanties_eind) . "<br>";
                }
             }
        }
    }
```

but this makes the code only show the dates 1-1 to 5-1. can somebody direct me to the right direction? maybe I'm doing it completely wrong but I don't know an easier solution to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were on the right track. I changed how you organize your data so iterating through them is simpler.

I also used `DateTime()` objects in my comparison because they are comparable. No need to format them as a string first.

```
$jaar = date('Y');
$vakanties = [
    'BeginKerst' => [
        'start' => new DateTime("$jaar-01-01"),
        'end'   => new DateTime("$jaar-01-05"),
    ],
    'Voorjaar' => [
        'start' => new DateTime("$jaar-02-22"),
        'end'   => new DateTime("$jaar-03-01"),
    ],
    'Mei' => [
        'start' => new DateTime("$jaar-04-25"),
        'end'   => new DateTime("$jaar-05-03"),
    ],
    'Zomer' => [
        'start' => new DateTime("$jaar-07-18"),
        'end'   => new DateTime("$jaar-08-30"),
    ],
    'EindKerst' => [
        'start' => new DateTime("$jaar-12-21"),
        'end'   => new DateTime("$jaar-12-31"),
    ],
    'Test' => [
        'start' =>  new DateTime("$jaar-05-20"),
        'end'   => new DateTime("$jaar-05-25"),
    ],
];

$now = new DateTime();
foreach ($vakanties as $name => $vakanty) {
    if ($now >= $vakanty['start'] && $now <= $vakanty['end']) {
        echo "today is in the middle of a vacation: " . $name;
    }
}
```

Output

```
today is in the middle of a vacation: Test
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/qf8vP)

Comment: Definitely a more elegant solution.